# Incorrect method to generate a random permutation of a finite set

Tags: probability, permutations

The Wikipedia article on the [Fisher Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) has a subsection on Potential Sources of Bias (Implementation Errors). It contains the following observation related to the possible outcomes when shuffling a three element array [1, 2, 3] using an incorrect implementation:

```
There are 6 possible permutations of this array (3! = 6), but the algorithm
produces 27 possible shuffles (3^3 = 27). In this case, [1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2], 
and [3, 2, 1] each result from 4 of the 27 shuffles, while each of the 
remaining 3 permutations occurs in 5 of the 27 shuffles.
```

I can easily enumerate the 27 possibilities using a probability tree and confirm that `123, 312, 321` occur four times each while `132, 213, 231` occur five times each.

This over representation is also confirmed by the [first image in this blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html).

Here's my question: what is so special about `132, 213, 231` that results in them occuring more often than `123, 312, 321`? Intuitively, I'd expect some sort of vague "symmetry" between the bias vs. non-bias cases, but that's clearly not true here.

Also, for the case of four elements, the same blog post indicates that `2341, 2314, 2143, 1342` occur far more frequently than the other permutations. Is there any particular reason for it?

Some related questions:

[How to shuffle a deck of cards?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252048/how-to-shuffle-a-deck-of-cards)

[Why is it that shuffling a deck so that all permutations are equally likely requires swapping only later elements?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109126/why-is-it-that-shuffling-a-deck-so-that-all-permutations-are-equally-likely-requ)

Comment: Some references: https://oeis.org/A192053, [Robbins and Bolker, *The bias of three pseudo-random shuffles*](https://eudml.org/doc/136878), [Schmidt and Simion, *Card shuffling and a transformation on $S_n$*](https://eudml.org/doc/137476)