# Most probable permutation

Tags: probability, permutations

Suppose I have a deck of 52 cards, which I have numbered from 1 to 52. I then apply the following shuffling algorithm on the deck -

- Start from the first card. Then choose a random number from 1 to 52, and swap the first card with the card at the position of that number. So for example if the random number is 50, we swap the card with 1 and the card at position 50.
- Then move onto the card with 2 on it. Again select a random number between 1 and 52 and swap these two cards. Note that the card with 2 may get swapped with the cards before it as well, not only the ones after it.
- Continue this process until we reach the end of the deck.

Now I know that this will not produce a uniform distribution of the cards,e since we are also swapping the cards with ones behind them. What I am interested in is the most probable and least probable permutation of the cards obtained after such a shuffling. Can anyone tell me how to proceed on this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What work have you done on it so far? Also, I think it's worth noting that if you generate a 1 when you're on card 47, you'll be picking a card from in front of it.

Comment: I have written down the permutations for small cases like 3 or 4 and tried to generalize it for larger case, but I can't seem to see a pattern. Also I think it is a bit unclear on the original question, but the random number generated is the position not the number on the card. So if you generate 1 while on card 47, you will swap the first card with the 47th card whatever the numbers on them may be.

Comment: Exactly, so you aren't always swapping cards with ones behind them.

Comment: Yes, just that you may. If it was always with the ones infront, then all permutations would have probability 1/52 afaik.

Comment: It seems still misunderstandable. For what I gather, position is *never* important for determining what you swap. In step $n$, you swap the card with number $n$ with the card with number $x_n$, where $x_n$ is uniformly randomly seleted from $\{1,2,\ldots,52\}$.
If in step 47 you find that $x_{47}=1$, then you swap the card with number 47 (wherever it is) with the card with number 1 (wherever it is). At least that's my understanding.

Comment: @lngix Yeah, I have edited the question, seems like I made a mistake. So basically in step n what you are doing is swapping the nth card with the card at the xn position. So basically the number on those cards doesn't matter until the end when I want to know what permutation has been generated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913518/random-shuffling-of-an-array https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913414/min-and-max-probable-identity-permutation-in-google-codejam-2014-q-3 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490193/incorrect-method-to-generate-a-random-permutation-of-a-finite-set etc.